# CSS/JQuery selectors odd behaviour

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

When using the jquery selectors I stumbled at something odd.

My HTML:

```
<ul id="unordered-list">
    <li>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <input type="text" size="40"/>
        <input type="text" size="40"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <input type="text" size="40"/>
        <input type="text" size="40"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now if I were to select the first input in the first input to add some css I one would use this:

```
$("#unordered-list li:nth-child(1) input:nth-child(1)").css("border", "5px solid red");
```

Now i would think this is what the browser would do this:
1. Browser selects the `#unordered-list` element.
2. Browser then selects the first li element.
3. Browser then selects the first input element it finds.

But that doesn't happen, it selects nothing.
This is because it actually tries to select the img as it's the first child.

Looking at the documentation of JQuery nth:child:
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

They do the same thing:

```
<script>$("ul li:nth-child(2)").append("<span> - 2nd!</span>");</script>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle demonstrating the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/uQYMz/

This just doesn't seem logical, I would expect input:nth-child(1) to select the first of available inputs. Is this intended behaviour and if so is there a reason why this behaviour is chosen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) from the CSS Selectors spec:

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n, and has a parent element

It applies to all elements in a set of siblings, not all elements *of a specific type*. There is another selector for that, appropriately named [`:nth-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/):

```
$("#unordered-list li:nth-child(1) input:nth-of-type(1)").css("border", "5px solid red");
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQYMz/1/).

---

You could read your original selector as follows:

- Select the `#unordered-list` element
- Select an `li` element *if* the element at `:nth-child(1)` is an `li` element
- Select an `input` element *if* the element at `:nth-child(1)` is an `input` element

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add another possibility :

Instead of using `input:nth-of-type` you can also use `input:first-of-type`

*"Selects every `<input>` element that is the first `<input>` element of its parent"*

```
$("#unordered-list li:first-child input:first-of-type").css("border", "5px solid red");
```